# trouble presenting and dismissing a modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, modalviewcontroller

I have an OpenGL-ES app with a toolbar. When I touch the configure icon on my toolbar, my app displays a view with a bunch of configuration options using the following code:

```
optionsControllerOutlet.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
optionsControllerOutlet.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self.glView.superview addSubview:optionsControllerOutlet.view];
[self presentModalViewController:optionsControllerOutlet animated:YES];
```

and when I try to dismiss the view, the following code gets executed:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The view comes up fine except the animation is missing from the transition. When I try to dismiss the view, nothing happens. Any idea why there is no animation and it's not dismissing? I'm just starting to wrap my head around view controllers and how to work with them. I can get it to work by using the following line to dismiss the view, but I'd like to get this working properly:

```
[optionsControllerOutlet.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need

```
[self.glView.superview addSubview:optionsControllerOutlet.view]
```

Nor should you need the removeSubview method. The modal view is supposed to take care of its presentation. So your error might be somewhere else.

Regarding dismissal, where are you calling:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This is meant to be sent to the view controller that presesnts the modal view controller, i.e. the parent view controller. Typically, you set the parent as the delegate and then call a method that dismisses the current modal view from within the parent.

Or, if you want to call it from the modal view itself, it is possible to run:

[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of [self.glView.superview addSubview:optionsControllerOutlet.view]; ?

Comment: If I do that, it still runs but doesn't show my view. I should also add that this is a window based application, not a view based application, so I'm not sure how that changes how I need to approach this.